# How to get a structure similar to a One Hot Encoding but without the binary coding (just 0s and positive numbers in the 1000s)?

Tags: r

I am trying to transform the data frame in a way to only have one numeric value greater than zero per row while the other values in the same row are zeros. Below is a chunk of code that can help explain what I am attempting to achieve:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Id = letters[1:9] , Value = floor(rnorm(9, mean = 10, sd = 1)), Value2 = 0)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Value3 = ifelse(df$Value > mean(df$Value), floor(rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 10, sd = 1)), 0))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(no.Zeros = apply(df[, 2:4], 1, function(x) length(x[x == 0])))
```

Essentially, for every row that has the value 1 in the last column (`no.Zeros`), I would like to have that row duplicated twice to have a new pair of rows with two zeroes in each row along with the remaining non zero value instead of having one zero as shown in the current row. 
Concretely, the final result should be if id "a" has values 11, 0, 9; then there should be two rows with id "a": the first would be 11, 0, 0 and the second 0, 0, 9. Also, the code may involve a for (or an implicit) loop as I am working with a fairly large data frame (about 70,000 rows).

Please let me know how this can be done. Thank you

Comment: It is not clear to me.  Did you meant `df %>% filter(no.Zeros ==1) %>% mutate(Value3 = 0) %>% bind_rows(df, .) %>% arrange(Id)`

Comment: The final result should be if id "a" has values 11, 0, 9; there should be two rows with id "a": the first would be 11, 0, 0 and the second 0, 0, 9. Also, the code may involve a for (or an implicit) loop as i am working with a fairly large data frame (about 70, 000 rows).  Each row will take 3 values: two zeros and a numeric value greater than zero. Please let me know if this helps. Thank you

Comment: Please update the expected output in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from another post revolving around the same question. Courtesy of @MrFlick

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  gather("Value3", "Value2", -Id) %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  filter(Value3 > 0) %>% 
  spread(Value3, Value2, fill= 0) %>% 
  select(-c(rowid, no.Zeros)) %>%
  arrange(Id) 


df <- filter(df, rowSums(df[, 2:4]) != 0)
```

Thank you for your time